# Where is the value_learner package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to find a source for the value_learner package described here: http://wiki.ros.org/value_learner

Unfortunately, the only source location I can find is the svn repo described [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/sandbox/value_learner/), but this version seems to be different from the one described in the wiki page.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197899/where-is-the-value_learner-package?/) by [highencast](https://answers.ros.org/users/3333/highencast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found at least one version of it on the old code.ros.org repository:

https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/browser/branches/trunk_cturtle/sandbox/value_learner?rev=46744

You might find a newer version if you look around in there. Also if you find something you want to work with I would highly recommend forking it to github or google code, since code.ros.org may go away at anytime.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [highencast](https://answers.ros.org/users/3333/highencast/) on 2014-11-20**:
Thank you. It looks like even the newest version (@ 55339) does not have all the launch files described on the wiki page. I guess this is a lost package? :/

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-20**:
It may have been moved somewhere else in the svn tree, but I don't know, I've never worked with that package.